# Select 2nd ancestor of clicked element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to get 2nd ancestor of clicked element?

It returns nothing: 
`$(this).parent().parent().find('.TITLE')`, 
`$(this).closest('.TITLE').text()`

It referrs to this code:

```
<div class="ELEMENT_LISTY" style="display:none">
<div class="TITLE" id="id_196">sadfsfsdfgds</div>
<div class="BUTTONY PRE">
<div class="POGLAD"></div>
<div class="ZMIEN_NAZWE"></div>
<div class="USUN"></div>
</div>
</div>

function przygotuj_ZmianeNazwy() {
    $(".PRE .ZMIEN_NAZWE,.NEW .ZMIEN_NAZWE").click(function() {

        $("#DIALOG3").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            show: 'scale', 
            hide: 'puff',
            buttons: {
                "Dodaj": function() {
                    var el = $("#input_ZmienNazwe").val();
                    if(el !== '' && el !== null) {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        var title = $(this).closest('.TITLE').text() // I AM CLICKING ON ELEMENT AMONG MANY, WANT TO SELECT ANCESTOR TEXT FROM THIS I CLICKED ON
                        alert(title);
                        //ajax_zmienNazwe(title);
                    }
                },
                "Anuluj": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#input_ZmienNazwe").blur();
                }
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("input_ZmienNazwe").focus();
    });
```

Comment: Show us your HTML, what you posted should work.

Comment: My question is updated for you.

Comment: Are you sure that `this` is what you think it is?

Comment: Matt Burland I don't know, yet this is not working so probably not. I need contents of .TITLE for clicked `<div class="ZMIEN_NAZWE"></div>` (there can be many of them, so selecting clicked one is a must)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a jsFiddle which works here http://jsfiddle.net/stJHG/1/. You need to adapt your code to the following:

```
$(".PRE .ZMIEN_NAZWE,.NEW .ZMIEN_NAZWE").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('.ELEMENT_LISTY').find('.TITLE').text());        
});​
```

`.TITLE` is not actually an ancestor of your element, but `.ZMIEN_NAZWE` and `.TITLE` have a common ancestor which is `.ELEMENT_LISTY`. So you have to select this one and then search it's children for `.TITLE`.

(Also I don't think your `style="display:none"` was in the place where you ment it to be, the clickable element was hidden as well)

Comment: Please include your code in the answer. If JSFiddle goes away or goes down this answer is not nearly as helpful.